# A non-compact $ T_{2} $ space which is not a k - space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called k - space  provided it has the property that any subset $ S $ such that $ S \cap K $ is closed for all closed compact $ K $ is  itself closed.

A topological space is called $ KC$ - space  provided every compact sets are closed.

A topological space is called $ US $ - space  provided each convergent sequence has unique

limit.

$ T2⇒ KC ⇒ US ⇒ T1 $

***Theorem:*** Let $ X $ be a $ KC $ space . Then $ X ^ { * } $ ( one point compatification of $ X $ ) is $ KC $ iff $ X $ is a k space.

To show that a $ US $ space is not $ KC$ space. let $ X $  be a non- compact $ T_{2} $ space  which is not a k- space, so according upper theorem $ X^{*} $ is compact $ US $ but not $ KC $ .for example:

A non-compact  $ T_{2} $ space which is not a k - space. Let $ X = N \cup \{ b\} $ , where $ b \in \beta\mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N} $ . If $ S $ is any infinite subset of $ \mathbb{N}$ , neither $ S $ nor $ S \cup \{ b \} $
 is closed in . Hence neither is compact. Thus $ X $ is pseudo - finite ,i.e. all its compact sets are finite. if $ X $ were a k - space , it would , being pseudo- finite, be discrete.

> why is it right that :If $ S $ is any infinite subset of $ \mathbb{N}$ , neither $ S $ nor $ S \cup \{ b \} $
>    is closed in . Hence neither is compact. Thus $ X $ is pseudo - finite ,i.e. all its compact sets are finite. if $ X $ were a k - space , it would , being pseudo- finite, be disceret." ?

Comment: Did you want to write: " neither $ S $ nor $ S \cup \{ b \} $
 is closed in $\beta\mathbb N"? The current version of the post ends with: "closed in" and it does not say where.

Comment: Habib: It seems that you have already at least four different accounts on this site: [88416](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/88416/habib),
[88471](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/88471/habib),
[88563](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/88563/habib),
[88913](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/88913/habib). I guess registering would make your life much easier. And then you could merge your older accounts (or ask the moderators to do so, if you are unable to do it).

Answer (score 1):

> why is it right that :If $ S $ is any infinite subset of $ \mathbb{N}$ , neither $ S $ nor $ S \cup \{ b \} $
>    is closed in . Hence neither is compact.

I suppose you meant to say *closed in $\beta\mathbb{N}$*.

The closure of $S$ in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ consists of all ultrafilters<sup>1</sup> containing $S$. If $S$ is infinite, there are at least two such ultrafilters; to see this you can, for example, divide $S$ into two disjoint infinite subsets $S=A\cup B$ and take one free ultrafilter containing $A$ and $S$ and another one containing $B$ and $S$.

You can make basically the same argument using Engelking, Corollary 3.6.2: Every pair of completely separated subsets of a Tychonoff space $X$ has
disjoint closures in $\beta X$.

Two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a topological space $X$ are called *completely
separated* if there exists a continuous function
$f \colon X\to I$ such that $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$. We say that $f$ separates sets $A$ and $B$.

Clearly, any two disjoint subsets of a discrete space are completely separated.

(Basically all you need for this argument to work is to show that closure of $S$ in $\beta\mathbb N$ contains at least two points from $\beta\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$.)

> Thus $ X $ is pseudo - finite ,i.e. all its compact sets are finite. if $ X $ were a k - space , it would , being pseudo- finite, be disceret." ?

If we work with a $T_1$-space, all finite subsets are closed. Now we have that for any compact subset $K$ any any subset $V$ the set $V\cap K$ is finite, and thus closed. This shows that every subset $V\subseteq X$ is closed.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am using a construction of $\beta\mathbb N$ using ultrafilters.

The construction of $\beta\mathbb N$ using ultrafilters is briefly described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers).
You can find it also in many [internet resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stone+cech+compactification%22+ultrafilters) and [books](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22stone+cech+compactification%22+ultrafilters).

For example, it is described here:

- [Chapter I.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=mjmPHAhJkmYC&pg=PA61) in *Hindman N., Strauss D. Algebra in the Stone-Čech compactification*
- Chapter II.14 in *Todorcevic S. [Topics in topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=aNYZAQAAIAAJ)* (Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1652).

Comment: what do you mean about:The closure of S in βN consists of all ultrafilters containing S. why you use ultrafiles?

Comment: @habib Are you familiar with the construction of $\beta\mathbb N$ as a topological space on the set of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Although I study a lot about βN , I am not very good at notion of  the construction of  βN and βN - N as a topological space, and ultrafilter on them!   please help me.Thanks.

Comment: @habib I tried my best. But you still [haven't clarified](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459300/a-non-compact-t-2-space-which-is-not-a-k-space/459304?noredirect=1#comment988652_459300) your post. BTW if you register, you will be able to [talk in chat](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) as soon as you get 20 rep points. (Maybe some users would be able to help you in chat.) I guess that you have earned at least 20 points, if you add reputation from your different accdounts.